# Setting sounds for local notifications on a 3G iPhone running iOS4

Tags: iphone, audio, notifications

I have successfully scheduled local notifications in my app using the code below:

```
Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");

    if (cls != nil) {

        UILocalNotification *notification = [[cls alloc] init];
        notification.fireDate = self.alarmNotificationDate;
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        notification.alertBody = @"Alarm is due";
        notification.alertAction = @"Show Alarm";

        notification.soundName = @"alarm.mp3";

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
        [notification release];
```

Where self.alarmNotificationDate is a NSDate assign in another method.

All works fine in the simulator, but when I test on my trusted old iPhone 3G running iOS4 I get the notification, but only with the default sound.

I have tried with different sound files but no success.

Any clue why it could be like this and how to correct it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UILocalNotification does not support mp3. It only supports the formats and containers mentioned on the reference page.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

> Because custom alert sounds are played
>   by the iOS system-sound facility, they
>   must be in one of the following audio
>   data formats:
>
> ```
>   Linear PCM
>   MA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
>   µLaw
>   aLaw
> ```
>
> You can package the audio data in an
>   aiff, wav, or caf file.

Answer (score 3):

There could be a couple of reasons:

1. Is your sound file included in your bundle? (most likely, seeing as it works on the simulator)
2. The Apple documentation says to not use compressed audio formats. See the link [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103). The reason for this being that the iPhone hardware can only play one compressed audio file at a time, and so it is not recommended to use one for the alarm as well, in case the user is already listening to a song from iTunes.

Comment: I'm currently using a MP3 so that could be the case. Will try with another format and see how it works. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for late feedback but I got stuck in another project. Tested with an AIF file and worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you spell the name of the sound using the same upper/lower case encoding in both the file name and the filename?

Comment: I have had that problem before, so whenever something like this doesn't work I always copy the actual filename into the code. But thanks for your suggestion.