# Set UILocal notification sound set large size Music file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am working on Alarm application in which I want to set Large Sound file in `UILocalnotification` sound name but somehow its won't playing File whose duration is more than 30 seconds.

So what can I do now can there it be some other solution for that?

Comment: [Check this answer and solve your problem][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716966/setting-sounds-for-local-notifications-on-a-3g-iphone-running-ios4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UILocal Notifications allow sounds to be played for 30 seconds only.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the `soundName` property of `UILocalNotification` says:

> Sounds that last longer than 30 seconds are not supported. If you
>   specify a file with a sound that plays over 30 seconds, the default
>   sound is played instead.

Unfortunately, I don't think you are going to find a workaround that allows you to play longer sound files.